# how to save a result from a mongoose query into a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

there are some questions here regarding how to save a result from a query into a javascript variable.

Here is the problem. This is my code,

```
router.put('/recognize/:youtuber', (req, res, next) => {
YtbReqTb.find({ 'ytbChannel' : req.params.youtuber }).exec()
    .then(doc => {
        res.status(200).json(doc)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

and this is the result.

```
{
        "_id": "6013a229cf5cfa2b1cc70d5d",
        "ytbChannel": "aaa",
        "ytbProfile": "../images/test.jpg",
        "ytbSubscribe": 2820000,
        "ytbHits": 22820000,
}
```

I want to save a result from a mongoose query into a javascript variable like this,

```
const result_1 = YtbReqTb.find({ 'ytbChannel' : req.params.youtuber });
```

or

```
const result_1 = YtbReqTb.find({ 'ytbChannel' : req.params.youtuber }).exec()
    .then(doc => {
        res.status(200).json(doc)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
```

but the result_1 comes only as undefined.

please help me.

Comment: put `await` in your first try `const result_1 = await YtbReqTb.find` and put `async` in your function `router.put('/recognize/:youtuber', async (req, res, next)`.

Comment: oh thank you, it's settled. :)